# If statement in Awk command

Tags: awk

I have data like:

```
13979  1
13980  2
13986  3
14023  4
15671  5
```

I'd like first to count difference between two adjacent values of the first column (13980-13979;13986-13980;14023-13986; etc). Then i'd like to print out string if the current difference is greater then 20. In my example :

```
14023  4
15671  5
```

My code:

```
cat file.txt | awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN {x=13979}; {print $1-x} ; {x=$1}'
```

But how add `if` statement to my code example?

Comment: Check out the [tag:awk] [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) for more information about how to write idiomatic awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '($1-prev)>20 && prev;{prev=$1}'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '($1-prev)>20 && FNR>1;{prev=$1}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
14023  4
15671  5
```

***Explanation:*** Adding an explanation too here(following is only for explanation purposes not for running).

```
awk '           ##Starting awk script from here.
($1-prev)>20    ##Checking condition here if subtraction of $1(first field) and variable prev is greater than 20(1st condition)
&&              ##Putting AND condition to check multiple conditions here.
prev;           ##Checking if variable prev is NOT NULL, if both conditions are TRUE then do following.
{
prev=$1         ##Setting variable prev value as $1(first field of current line).
}'  Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: is it better to change `&& prev` into `&& NR>1` ?

Comment: @Kent definitely. There's no reason to think `prev` cannot be zero so using `&& prev` instead of `&& NR>1` would be a bug.

Comment: Your first awk `'($1-prev)>20 && prev;{prev=$1}'` would fail if the value of `prev` is legit yet `0`. Your second awk works great, but I might do `'FNR>1 && ($1-prev)>20; {prev=$1}'` just to apply that the test is only done after `prev` has been set by the next clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk that is close to the code that you have but does actually work:

```
awk -F"\t" -v dif=20 'FNR==1{x=$1; next}  # first record, set x
                      ($1-x)>dif  # if this is true -- print
                      {x=$1}' file.txt
```